# regex extract big query with numeric data

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

how would I be able to grab the number 2627995 from this string

```
"hellotest/2627995?hl=en"
```

I want to grab the number 2627995, here is my current regex but it does not work when I use regex extract from big query

```
(\/)\d{7,7}

SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(DESC, r"(\/)\d{7,7}")
  AS number
FROM
  `string table`
```

here is the output

[image: error]

Thank you!!

Comment: The slash is not a special character in regex: You neither need to use brackets (no need to capture it) nor escape it. ie `\/` is identical to just `/`

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to match all digits coming after the last path separator, before either the start of the query parameter, or the end of the URL.

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(DESC, r"/(\d+)(?:\?|$)") AS number
FROM `string table`
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: `r"\/(\d+)"`

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns the slash because you *captured* it (see the parentheses in `(\/)\d{7,7}`). `REGEXP_EXTRACT` only returns the *captured* substring.

Thus, you could just wrap the other part of your regex with the parentheses:

```sql
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(DESC, r"/(\d{7})")
  AS number
FROM
  `string table`
```

**NOTE**:

- In BigQuery, regex is specified with string literals, not regex literals  (that are usually delimited with forward slashes), that is why you do not need to escape the `/` char (it is not a special regex metacharacter)
- `{7,7}` is equal to `{7}` limiting quantifier, meaning *seven occurrences*.

Also, if you are sure the number is at the end of string or is followed with a query string, you can enhance it as

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(DESC, r"/(\d+)(?:[?#]|$)")
```

where the regex means

- `/` - a `/` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (the actual output): one or more digits
- `(?:[?#]|$)` - either `?` or `#` char, or end of string.